# How to read the secret in rancher?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rancher

I'm using rancher and I set a secret using the rancher's GUI. I'm trying to make my application read this secret. Let's say the secret is called `pass` and I want to read it. Being known with docker, I wrote the following code:

```
    readDockerSecret: function(secretName) {
        return fs.readFileSync(`/run/secrets/${secretName}`, 'utf8');
    }
    // code

    // read secret
    try {
        var secretName = "pass";
        var pass = utils.readDockerSecret(pass);
    } catch (err) {
        if (err.code !== 'ENOENT') {
            logger.error(`An error occurred while trying to read the secret: ${secretName}. Err: ${err}`);
        } else {
            logger.debug(`Could not find the secret: ${secretName}. Err: ${err}`);
        }
    }
```

But when I use it in rancher, it never finds the secret. In the rancher shell in the GUI I can see that I have the following herechy:

```
ls -la /run/secrets
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 27 Aug 10 11:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 21 Aug 10 10:53 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 40 Aug 10 11:02 credentials.d
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 28 Aug 10 11:02 kubernetes.io
```

`credentials.d` is empty. But `kubernetes.io` contains:

```
/run/secrets/kubernetes.io
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  28 Aug 10 11:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  27 Aug 10 11:02 ..
drwxrwxrwt 3 root root 140 Aug 10 11:02 serviceaccount

 ls -la  /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/
total 0
drwxrwxrwt 3 root root 140 Aug 10 11:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  28 Aug 10 11:02 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 100 Aug 10 11:02 ..2020_08_10_11_02_18.157580662
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  31 Aug 10 11:02 ..data -> ..2020_08_10_11_02_18.157580662
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  13 Aug 10 11:02 ca.crt -> ..data/ca.crt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  16 Aug 10 11:02 namespace -> ..data/namespace
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12 Aug 10 11:02 token -> ..data/token
```

No sign for `pass` anywhere. Tried also to grep but without any luck. How should I read the secret in rancher?

**EDIT**: The screenshot:

[image]

In the yaml we have:

```
   spec:
      containers:
      - envFrom:
        - prefix: pass
          secretRef:
            name: pass
            optional: false
        image: <image-url>
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: <app-name>
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          capabilities: {}
          privileged: false
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
          runAsNonRoot: false
        stdin: true
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        tty: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: pass
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status:
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use a secret from inside a pod, you first need to "mount" that secret into the pod, either as an environment variable or a file. The [secrets docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets) describe in detail how to do that.

Comment: I did it using rancher's GUI and then it redeployed. But it's still not there :/

Comment: What did you do, exactly? I'm not that familiar with Racher's UI, can you maybe show a screenshot?

Comment: I added the screenshot

Comment: Ok, it looks like it's exposed as an environment variable. I can't figure out exactly the name (it depends on your `Secret`'s structure), but you can see all environment variables in the pod by running `kubectl exec pod-name -- printenv`. Then you can access it from Node.js by using `process.env.env_var_name`.

Comment: I printed all the envs `console.log(process.env);` and unfortunately it isn't there. Any idea why?

Comment: How does your `Secret` look like?

Comment: navigate to Catalog -> Library and search for the Rancher Secrets entry.  Is it enabled?
What's the Rancher version? Is it at least 1.6?

Comment: The Rancher version is v2.3.6. Where is `Catalog->Library`? I think it's in the v1x version.